# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Tags: python, printing, raspberry-pi, nonetype

I'am quite new to python and I am developing a passport scanner with a RaspberryPi and the passport eye module. In the end it prints outs the outcome of the scanned image. However, I also want to print an outcome if the scanner isn't able tot detect a MRZ code.

I tried some things but couldn't figure it out, here is a example in short:

```
mrz = read_mrz("test.jpg")
mrz_data = mrz.to_dict()

if mrz.to_dict == None:
 print("Invalid document")

else:
 print(mrz_data["names"])
```

> Error in 
> mrz_data = mrz.to_dict() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

EDIT: Is there a way to print when the error is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Comment: Not sure it cause any problem here, but it is good practice to write `something is None` rather than `something == None`

Comment: You must perform the check on the ``None``'able value – checking it after working with the value is too late. So there should be some ``if mrz is None:`` right after attempting the read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://github.com/konstantint/PassportEye#usage) -

> The returned object (unless it is None, which means no ROI was detected) contains the fields extracted from the MRZ along with some metainformation

Looks like the image that you are using returns `None`. In line 2 when you call the `to_dict()` on `None`, it throws the exception `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`

This can be fixed as follows

```
if mrz == None:
 print("Invalid document")

else:
 print(mrz.to_dict()["names"])
```